# AddClass to a keyboard shortcut anchor for feedback

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts, addclass

I am trying to simply add some CSS for an anchor link I have a keyboard shortcut setup for. The menu item.

`<a id="about">About The Company</a>`

```
shortcut.add("a",function() {
    $("#about").trigger('click');  
    },{
    'disable_in_input':true
});
```

When the keyboard 'a' is selected, I want to get the "About The Company" anchor to fade into red for a second to give the user feedback that it has been selected.

This is the script I'm using fyi: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

```
shortcut.add("a",function() {
    $("#about").hide().css('color','#ff0000').fadeIn(700);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That adds the CSS, but I only want it to remain for a second and the return to normal color. So it will fadeIn (wait a second).. fadeOut. Is that possible?